# How can I return back to my Activity from GPS settings window

Tags: android, gps

I am having a problem in my Activity, which can take the control to the android mobile GPS settings to have user to switch on/off the GPS, But I am unable to retrun back to my activity. when I press back button, It is directly going to Home of the mobile, not coming back my Activity from where I send signal to settings. can anyone tell me the solution for this.

```
if(!lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) { 
    startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
```

---

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    Log.e("","OnActivity Result...");
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (resultCode == GPS_LOC) {
       switch (requestCode) {
          case GPS_LOC:
              //super.onCreate(inst);
              super.onResume();
              //super.finish();
           break;
        }
     }  
 }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Works for me. Are you sure you have ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission set in your manifest? Are you sure startActivityForResult() is being called?

Also, what is GPS_LOC?

Here's my code that works:

```
public class main extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        findViewById(R.id.button1).setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (resultCode == 1) {
           switch (requestCode) {
              case 1:
               break;
            }
         }  
     }
}
```

Comment: GPS_LOC is just a constant,istead of '1' in your code and I was setting all the required permissions, However I got the solution, Actually my activity was automatically calling stop when i was pressing back button from the settings, so I  just called Restart() from onStop of my Activity, problem solved.

Comment: Your activity should be having stop called since it was no longer visible. However once the child activity is dismissed it will be started and resumed. Were you calling finish() from OnStop()?

Comment: No I am just calling onRestart() from onStop() to resolve the problem, because when it is coming out of settings, it is calling onStop() on myActivity,that is the reason myActivity is closing and the control goes to Mobile home. So I just called onRestart() from onStop(), this way I resolved my problem

Comment: I had the same problem which was caused by me having set the noHistory  flag in the manifest to true, so my activity was removed from the history as I started the GPS settings. Maybe something similar is going on with you? Seems like restarting in onStop isn't that good of an idea... You can still clear the activity from the history with "intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);"

Comment: btw resultCode is always 0 whether user enabled location or not

Comment: @gturedi I have the same issue. Did you find the solution?

Comment: @hasnain_ahmad infact that point you do not need resultCode because you can detect if user enabled location services using LocationManager class like this: locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER) or locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_NETWORK)

Comment: @dhaag23 is there any possible way to get back result on service ?

Comment: @dhaag23 It works on physical back press,  but how can acheive in back arrow ?

Comment: My activity gets destroyed when I start that intent tor result.. what can be the reason ? How to prevent it ?

Comment: Nowadays startActivityForResult is deprecated, it is better to use ActivityResultLauncher as mentioned in the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62671106/onactivityresult-method-is-deprecated-what-is-the-alternative)

Answer (score 1):

```
android:noHistory="true"
```

removing above from menifest file works for me but data is null inside onActivityResult

Answer (score 0):

On back press from the settings location activity, **On Resume** is called from the activity that called 
`startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1);`

Therefore from there you can check if location has been enabled by

```
`if(lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER )) {//add your logic here }`
```