# back button not taking me to previous activity, rather home screen

Tags: android, gps, maps, location, google-maps-android-api-2

In my activity, I am performing a check if both the GPS and WIFI location servies are off.

Incase both are off, the intent of the location services is triggered.
However, when I press the back button, I cannot come back to my activity, rather homescreen.
Thus the screen is stuck in the location settings page.

Note that I am extending FragmentActivity and using SupportMapFragment.

```
        int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

    if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS)
    { // Google Play Services are not available

        int requestCode = 10;
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this,requestCode);
        dialog.show();

    } else
    { 

        fm = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        googleMap = fm.getMap();
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if(locationManager != null)
        {
            gpsIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            networkIsEnabled = locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

            if(gpsIsEnabled==false && networkIsEnabled==false)
            {
                Log.i("code","both wifi and gps off.");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
            }
            else
            {
                Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
                String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

                if (location != null)
                {
                    onLocationChanged(location);
                }

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, this);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Log.i("app","null.");
        }
```

Comment: what do you mean by "screen is stuck in the location settings page"? Is your problem "when you press back from location services you reach home screen in place of your activity?"

Comment: no. my mainactivity which extends fragment activity loads, and inside onCreate() there is a call for an intent to open the location settings page (where i can turn on or off gps), however, once I finish what I have to do in there, pressing the back button does not bring me back to my mainactivity. It just takes me off to home screen of my phone (as if home button is pressed). ie, the back button does not take me to previous activity in stack.

Comment: Mitesh, I added the code.

Comment: please post full code specially the code that you are doing for back press

Comment: Mitesh, there is no code for back press in this fragmentActivity, I am doing the back press from ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS, but it stays there. I do not know if fragmentActivities do not handle back presses like normal Activities.

Comment: startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), 1)

Comment: try see if this works  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    }

Comment: gladmax, it does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in your Manifest.

```
public class main extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // If Gps and Wifi are off

               Intent mIntent= new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
               mIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
               startActivityForResult(mIntent, 1);
        }
    });
}

@Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1) {
       switch (requestCode) {
          case 1:
               // Fetch Location..
           break;
        }
     }  
 }
```

Comment: Mitesh, still when the back is pressed I am not getting to the activity that it caused, rather the back press is acting like home button.

Comment: Did you mentioned the permission??

Comment: @tony9099 see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987379/how-can-i-return-back-to-my-activity-from-gps-settings-window

Comment: Mitesh, still no good. I also realized that the back press sometimes works, however, after using it couple of times, it causes the app to freeze and become slow.

Comment: Did you set anything onPause() or onResume()?

Comment: I hope you are removing location updates during onPause() and on registering back onResume().

Comment: yes. it's ok, I triend another method and got the job done using checkboxes without the need to implement on back press. thanks for your input