# Android detect location settings

Tags: android, android-location

I'm using the new Location API in my app and I'm wondering how to detect if I the user has location access enabled on there phone.

I'm setting up a LocationClient and running a LocationRequest. How would I run a check before doing this to see if I can actually get the users location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your onConnected you could call a method like these:

```
private boolean checkLocationProviders()
{
    if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        if(mLocationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

If false is returned, you can open the Settings screen in this way:

```
startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
```

Comment: Hi fasteque, when startActivity(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS)); , when It return of the activity, is there a way to know it has come back, and check for the GPS again? e.g. can we use startActivityForResult for this purpose?

Comment: @Elye I guess you can use `startActivityForResult` so you know when the user has left the setting screen, give it a try to see if it's actually true. Here you can find some hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987379/how-can-i-return-back-to-my-activity-from-gps-settings-window - otherwise you can check in your Activity's `onResume`. Please also notice that new Google Play Services release (7.0) will improve this mechanism as reported here: http://android-developers.blogspot.ch/2015/03/google-play-services-70-places-everyone.html