# Open app settings and get the result after user enabled/disabled certain features?

Tags: android, startactivityforresult

in my app I have the option for the user to open the settings and allow location. How can I know that the user turned on the location after I navigated into the settings screen? This is how start the settings activity.

```
if(!gps_enabled && !network_enabled) {
            // notify user
            new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                    .setMessage(R.string.gps_network_not_enabled)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.open_location_settings, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                            startActivityForResult(new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS), isGpsTurnedOnResult );
                        }
                    }).setNegativeButton(R.string.Cancel,null)
                    .show();
        }
```

This is how I try to get the result:

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }
```

When I check `data` I see that it's null, is there a way I can know that the user turned the location on? Of course I can check it using `LocationManager`, but this is not the solution I want unless it's the only thing that possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I return back to my Activity from GPS settings window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5987379/how-can-i-return-back-to-my-activity-from-gps-settings-window)

Answer (score 0):

Build location setting

```
LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder()
     .addLocationRequest(locationRequest);

LocationSettingsRequest.Builder builder = new LocationSettingsRequest.Builder();

// ...

SettingsClient client = LocationServices.getSettingsClient(this);
Task<LocationSettingsResponse> task = client.checkLocationSettings(builder.build());
```

Prompt the user to change location settings

```
task.addOnSuccessListener(this, new OnSuccessListener<LocationSettingsResponse>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(LocationSettingsResponse locationSettingsResponse) {
        // All location settings are satisfied. The client can initialize
        // location requests here.
        // ...
    }
});

task.addOnFailureListener(this, new OnFailureListener() {
    @Override
    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
        if (e instanceof ResolvableApiException) {
            // Location settings are not satisfied, but this can be fixed
            // by showing the user a dialog.
            try {
                // Show the dialog by calling startResolutionForResult(),
                // and check the result in onActivityResult().
                ResolvableApiException resolvable = (ResolvableApiException) e;
                resolvable.startResolutionForResult(MainActivity.this,
                        REQUEST_CHECK_SETTINGS);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException sendEx) {
                // Ignore the error.
            }
        }
    }
});
```